# MySQL: join fields with foreign key references

Tags: mysql, join, reference, foreign-keys, field

**What I wanna do**

I'm creating a html form in which I want to auto-create the fields (e.g. `<input type="text">`, `<textarea>`, `<select>`). For this purpose I do the MySQL-query `"SHOW FIELDS from $table"`.

a) Now I want to join the `REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA`, `REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME`, `REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME` from the `information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` to the `FIELDS`-table.

b) Later on I would like to query the *possible values for each foreign key* in the referenced table, to provide a html `<select>`-menu, in which the user can choose between one of the presets.

**Questions**

To a) How can I join these two within MySQL?

To a) and b) I'm using 2 data objects (one for the FIELDS and References, another one for the referenced values). Do you think it's a good way or are there better ways?

EDIT

**Explanation**

***JSON of fields and references***

```
[
    {
        "Field": "id",
        ...
        "Key": "PRI",
        ...
        "foreign_db": "null",
        "foreign_table": "null",
        "foreign_column": "null"
    },
    {
        "Field": "url",
        ...
        "Key": "UNI",
        ...
        "foreign_db": "null",
        "foreign_table": "null",
        "foreign_column": "null"
    },
    {
        "Field": "sitemap__site_id",
        ...
        "Key": "MUL",
        ...
        "foreign_db": "my_db",
        "foreign_table": "sitemap",
        "foreign_column": "site_id"
    }
]
```

***JSON of reference column values***

```
[
    {
        "Field": "sitemap__site_id",
        "Value": "index" 
    },
    {
        "Field": "sitemap__site_id",
        "Value": "error" 
    },
    {
        "Field": "sitemap__site_id",
        "Value": "about" 
    }
]
```

Put together, I'm able to auto-create a html `<form>` in which each field is created dependent on its field `Type` (e.g. an text `<input>` field for varchar(32) or `<textarea>` for varchar(512) AND a `<select>` field for the case, that I have to preset the possible entries due to the reference of a foreign key).

@rlanvin Hope this makes it clear.

So again: How can I get the first JSON object joined within MySQL? Or in general: How is this problem solved typically?

Comment: I did the join with PHP

Comment: @Jens Works fine so far (dynamically with AJAX), but it does not seem to be the best solution as I would like to get MySQL all work done as far as possible

Comment: I have no idea what is your second question about ("2 data objects?") but for the first one, you should be able to join with information_schema.columns, using table_schema and table_name as keys. Avoid for a real project though, I doubt it'll be efficient.

Comment: @rlanvin I'll try that. What would be your approach?

Comment: Vast question... I can't say what my approach would be without the big picture, which is beyond the scope of this question. However I can make two comments: 1) your JSON structure is too verbose (for example, `{"sitemap__site_id":["index", "error", "about"]}` would much easier to work with) and 2) consider the risks of exposing the raw structure of your tables without abstraction (what if you want a <select> on a field that isn't a FK? what if you want to make a field read-only? what if you want to hide a field from the form?).

Comment: Verbose JSON: Probably right. My example is bound to the relational data model. I have both in mind... III Risks of exposing: So you'd better provide individual forms for each table? What about e.g. using the comment column of information_schema.columns to handle cases like those you described? With 'risks' you did not target security risks primarily, right?

Comment: I should have said "risks and limitations". But yes "risks" as in "security risks". I do not know your architecture or your project, so maybe this doesn't apply, but I see at least 2 risks: 1) If your JSON is visible by the client (used in a JS or whatever), he can gain very detailed knowledge about the exact structure of your database. Though not exploitable directly as it is, it might facilitate/aggravate other exploits, so it's not something you want to show publicly 2) Accidentally making a field visible and editable, which could have serious security impacts.

Comment: But then again, it completely depends on what you're trying to do. If you're coding a PHPMyAdmin-like tool, then it's fine!

Comment: Ya, PHPMyAdmin-like is a good guess (not the whole functionality, but part of it in an easier way for me to work with). So 'paljon kiitoksia' so far for your kind help!!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

To a)

```
SELECT
    c.COLUMN_NAME AS 'Field',
    c.COLUMN_KEY AS 'Key',
    k.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA AS 'foreign_db', 
    k.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME AS 'foreign_table', 
    k.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME  AS 'foreign_column'
FROM
    information_schema.COLUMNS AS c
LEFT JOIN
    information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS k
ON 
    c.TABLE_SCHEMA = k.TABLE_SCHEMA
AND
    c.TABLE_NAME = k.TABLE_NAME
AND
    c.COLUMN_NAME = k.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE
    c.TABLE_SCHEMA = '$dbname'
AND
    c.TABLE_NAME = '$tableName'
```